# Deserializing multiple documents with `serde_yaml`

Tags: rust, yaml, deserialization, serde

I am saving in append mode a stream of events on a YAML log file, where each event is represented by an indivual document, like this:

```yaml
---
type: event
id: 1
---
type: trigger
id: 2
```

At some point later I want to iterate on these events, parsing each via `serde_yaml`. To my understanding though, `serde_yaml` doesn't seem to support parsing multiple documents from a single reader, as none of the available methods mention it, and trying to parse multiple documents at once results in a `MoreThanOneDocument` error.

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use serde_yaml;
use serde::{self, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "type", rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum Message {
    Event { id: i32 },
    Trigger { id: i32}, 
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let yaml = "---\ntype: event\nid: 1\n---\n\ntype: trigger\nid: 2";

    let v: Message = serde_yaml::from_reader(yaml.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", v);
    
    Ok(())
}
```

I'm totally new to Rust, so maybe I completely missed the point of `serde` and just did not understand how to do it.

How would you parse such YAML, please?

I cooked up something that looks like a working solution, but I think I'll try to post it among the answers instead, because I don't want to bias other answers too much towards my solution. I kindly encourage you to have a look at it as well however, any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation of [serde_yaml::Deserializer](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/latest/serde_yaml/struct.Deserializer.html#examples) shows an example very similar to yours. It would work like this:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "type", rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum Message {
    Event { id: i32 },
    Trigger { id: i32 },
}

fn main() {
    let yaml = "---\ntype: event\nid: 1\n---\ntype: trigger\nid: 2\n";

    for document in serde_yaml::Deserializer::from_str(yaml) {
        let v = Message::deserialize(document).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", v);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I totally missed this bit seeing all the examples from `serde::from_*()` functions.

Answer (score -1):

I really hope to find a native solution by using `serde` and `serde_yaml` only, but until then the way I got it working is as follows.

```rust
trait BufReaderYamlExt {
    fn read_next_yaml(&mut self) -> io::Result<Option<String>>;
}

impl<T: io::Read> BufReaderYamlExt for io::BufReader<T> {
    fn read_next_yaml(&mut self) -> io::Result<Option<String>> {
        const sep : &str = "\n---\n";
        let mut doc = String::with_capacity(200);
        while self.read_line(&mut doc)? > 0 {
            if doc.len() > sep.len() && doc.ends_with(sep) {
                doc.truncate(doc.len() - sep.len());
                break;
            }
        }
        if !doc.is_empty() {
            doc.shrink_to_fit();
            Ok(Some(doc))
        } else {
            Ok(None)
        }
    }
}
```

The trait extends the `BufReader` with an extra method that returns an optional owned `String` (or `None` at the end of the stream) containing just the portion with a single YAML document.

By iterating on it one could then apply `serde_json::from_str()` to parse the document into a `Message` struct.

```rust
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let yaml = "---\ntype: event\nid: 1\n\n---\n\ntype: trigger\nid: 2\n";
    let mut r = io::BufReader::new(yaml.as_bytes());
    
    while let Some(next) = r.read_next_yaml()? {
        let d: Message = serde_yaml::from_str(&next).unwrap();
        println!("parsed: {:?}", d);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I've made available the full source on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4219b30cb97645ce3ce563018d83599e) as well.

Comment: PS: please don't mind the arbitrary `with_capacity()` size of the string, I just set it to a reasonable size for my average document length.